# No se hacer este navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hola a todos estoy aprendiendo CSS y quería probar hacer una navbar que vi de una página. El tema es que no sé como hacer para que todos los elementos del navbar esten en sus correspondientes posiciones.

Resumen: Tengo los elementos puestos dentro del navbar pero no se como cambiarlos de lugar para que esten al igual que ese navbar. Que estilos me recomiendan usar o como haría? Gracias.

https://www.ovnipress.net/ --> Esta es la pagina web navbar
[image: navbar]

https://codepen.io/Tadiu/pen/eYZjMQM --> Esto es lo que intente.

Html:

```
<body>
<header>      
        <navbar>
            <ul class="nav__list">
                <a class="nav__item" id="logo" href="#logo"> <img id= "logo" src="https://www.solarenergy.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/icon_004240_256.png" /> </a>
              <li class="nav__item"> <a href="#categorias">CATEGORIAS</a> </li>
              <li class="nav__item"> <a href="#novedades">NOVEDADES</a> </li>
              <li class="nav__item"> <a href="#ofertas">OFERTAS</a> </li>
              <li class="nav__item"> <a href="#contacto">CONTACTO</a> </li>
            <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar..." class="header__searchbar">
          
          <a class="nav__login" id="login" href="#login"> <img id= "logo" src="https://zananerooz.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/User-profile.png" /></a>
      
      <a class="nav__cart" id="carrito" href="#carrito"> <img id= "logo" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/132115/isolated/lists/dcaf6e695736ac3b2717a39dbe4c9a42-shoppingcart-icon-silhouett.png" /> </svg>  </a>
            </ul>
          </navbar>
</header>
```

CSS(que hice y tiene todo centrado que es lo unico que pude):

```
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #logo {
        width: 60px;
        /*margin-right: 20rem;*/
        align-content: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    
    .nav__list {
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #cfd8dc;
        padding: 1rem 0;
        border-radius: 0.2rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 6rem;
    }
    
    .nav__item {
        list-style: none; /*remuevo los puntos*/
        margin-right: 1rem; 
    }
    
    .nav__item a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    }
    
    .nav__item a:hover {
        color: #29e6a7;
     }

.header__searchbar {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 32px;
    border-radius: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Agrega aquí tu código por favor

Comment: Gracias por recomedarme que me había olvidado. Ahí lo agregué.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El menu original tiene una estructura distinta, separando los elementos del inicio y fin, de los items de menu (`ul`) central, algo asi:

```
<navbar>
    <div class="navbar-left"><!-- logo --></div>
    <ul class="menu-container">
         <li><a href="/" >Inicio</a></li>
         <li><a href="/" >Productos</a>
            <ul><!--submenu--></ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="/contacto/">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-right"><!-- busqueda + carrito --></div>
</navbar>
```

Esto permite dividir la barra de navegacion en 3 partes. Por lo tanto algunos elementos que no son del menu se deben quitar del `<ul>` y dejar solo items del menu (`<li>`).

Asi, `navbar` pasa a ser el contenedor principal, que tiene el borde, sombra y tamaño (movido de `.nav__list` y agregando algunas propiedades flex, por ejemplo `align-items: center` para centrar verticalmente)

```
navbar{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #cfd8dc;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  height: 6rem;    
}
.navbar-right{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Ademas se requieren hacer ajustes adicionales para una vista responsiva (apta para una pantalla mas pequeña), considerando que el menu que tu usas es mas extenso (el original solo 3 elementos). Por ejemplo,

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
  navbar{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Aqui el ejemplo con los ajustes, basado en esto puedes hacer mejoras adicionales en distintos tamaños de pantalla.

https://codepen.io/fraigo/pen/eYZjjor

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme con este problema. Había pensado eso de separar los elementos y que no esten todo dentro del <ul>. Osea no se me separaban porque estaban todos adentro de la lista, no?
Lo de dividirlos en divs left y div right es algo muy interesante. Leyendo un poco sobre Html(ya que estoy aprendiendo) leí que se empezó a utilizar un poco menos los divs por las sections. Es verdad esto? Recomendas las sections sobre las divs? es lo mismo? Por esto mismo no utilizaba mucho divs pero viendo que las páginas lo usan mucho como que me quedaba esa duda.

Comment: + Estuve viendo que el space between hacia que se separen de esa forma. Si quisiera que haya espacio entre ellas pero que no esten pegado a las puntas tendria que sacarlo y como lo moveria?

Y lo de vista responsiva vi que usaste el flex wrap que tengo entendido los tira uno abajo de otro eso me re gustó. Recomendas usarlo siempre que tenga que hacer responsive? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para que haya espacio entre los elementos pero mas centrado puedes usar `justify-content: space-around`. Y si, `flex-wrap` es bueno usarlo siempre que desees que el contenido se distribuya en filas si no hay espacio suficiente, como en una pantalla pequeña.